# Google Places & M1 Macs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ios, swift

My Swift/iOS students are building apps with GooglePlaces. It seems GooglePlaces does not run in the simulator on M1 Macs, so anyone with an M1 has been building & running on iOS devices. I have one student who has an M1 Mac but is an Android user & doesn't have an iOS device.

- Is there a way to run GooglePlaces in the simulator on M1 Macs? If so, can you please point folks to newbie-friendly instructions (this is a zero-to-full stack university course, so many students are still fairly new to Xcode & iOS). If there are not clear instructions, I will adapt & create on my own if any instructions are available.
- If there is no way to run GooglePlaces on a simulator on M1 Macs, do we know when this will be available from Google?
- Any word on when GooglePlaces will use SwiftPackageManager? We'd like to get away from using Cocoapods, but the online documentation doesn't mention any SMP version of GooglePlaces is available.
  Thank you - sorry if I missed something on the forums, but my group of iOS devs in training are grateful for any help you can point us to.
  John

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround for M1 Macs, which is to open Xcode with Rosetta enabled.

Find the Xcode app in Finder, and right-click it, then "Get Info", then tick "Open using Rosetta", then reopen Xcode.

It should not be too hard for students to set up. It can be setup just once and reused afterwards.

[image]